# How is 100. legal?

Tags: c

I saw a calendar program written in C which just says `100.` instead of `100.00`. The program compiled without any issues.

My question is how is this legal. Shouldnt the C compiler not complain that there are no decimals after the `.`?

Advance thanks for your answers!

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? (And, specifically, why would you expect to need `00` instead of just `0`?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because section 6.4.4.2 of the language standard, *"Floating constants"* , defines them thusly:

```
floating-constant:
    decimal-floating-constant
    hexadecimal-floating-constant

decimal-floating-constant:
    fractional-constant exponent-part(opt) floating-suffix(opt)
    digit-sequence exponent-part floating-suffix(opt)

hexadecimal-floating-constant:
    hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-fractional-constant
    binary-exponent-part floating-suffixopt
    hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit-sequence
    binary-exponent-part floating-suffix(opt)

fractional-constant:
    digit-sequence(opt) . digit-sequence
    digit-sequence .

exponent-part:
    e sign(opt) digit-sequence
    E sign(opt) digit-sequence

sign: one of
    + -

digit-sequence:
    digit
    digit-sequence digit

hexadecimal-fractional-constant:
    hexadecimal-digit-sequence(opt) .
    hexadecimal-digit-sequence
    hexadecimal-digit-sequence .

binary-exponent-part:
    p sign(opt) digit-sequence
    P sign(opt) digit-sequence

hexadecimal-digit-sequence:
    hexadecimal-digit
    hexadecimal-digit-sequence hexadecimal-digit

floating-suffix: one of
    f l F L
```

Bottom line, **all** of the following would be valid floating point literals meaning "zero":

0.

.0

0.0

(Your "100." would be a valid `floating-constant`, as it is a `decimal-floating-constant` consisting of a `fractional-constant` (omitting the optional `exponent-part` and `floating-suffix`); it is a `digit-sequence` followed by a period, which is valid for a `fractional-constant` as by the second line of that noteable's definition.)

Answer (score 3):

No, for a double (and float) literal value, a C compiler does not require any decimals.

```
double d = 100.;
double d = 100.0;
double d = 100.000000;
```

Would all be legal, and represent the same value of 100 as a `double`

Comment: Do not forget `double d = .0;`. :)

Answer (score 0):

it is a legal and valid C program. it is a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

because when you put '.' your 100 turned to a double for compilers. also you see 100. but compiler understands 100.00